# Kdevelop execute project with parameters

Tags: c++, kdevelop

I am new to `Kdevelop` and I am trying for 2 hours to run a project based on input parameters in C++ style.

The code is here:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::string s = args[1]
   std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
}
```

I am trying to add the parameter, but it is crashing and saying

```
Process Error - Kdevelop
A shell meta character was included in the atguments for file launch ...
```

Can anyone tell me what is it about? Andhow can I fix it, or where shall I add the execution parameters?

I have placed them in the `Launch -> Configuration Launches -> Behaviour -> Arguments` see below

[image: Print Screen]

Please help

Comment: That normally is the way to do it so there is probably something wrong with the arguments that you are adding. Could you post them?

Comment: Shall I post them like in the Terminal mode meaning `./..//..//myfold/myPic.jpg`? I was putting them like `/home/usr/Pictures/pic.jpg`

Comment: `./..//..//......` is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments must be between quotes:

```
"/your folder and path/Your file"
```

or

```
"enter your parameter here"
```

instead of

```
just the parameter
```