# Kdevelop launch program after build execution

Tags: terminal, launch, kdevelop, kdevelop4

I'm using KDevelop.
My program creates a picture file.
So i'd like automatically open it after execution. HOw could I do this in the KDevelop??

I looked at this theme [Kdevelop execute project with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782403/kdevelop-execute-project-with-parameters) and my run-configuration is shown at the picture.

In the KDevelop's Run Tab I got the following launch command:

*Starting: /home/df/projects/topopt/build/topopt && xdg-open ~/projects/topopt/build/sample.gif*

Image viewer doesn't launch. But this command is correct, image viewer launches if I type this string in the terminal .

[image]

Comment: can you just keep the image viewer open and hit refresh any time after run ? not so convenient though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shell script, say run.sh,  with the following commands

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/df/projects/topopt/build/topopt
xdg-open ~/projects/topopt/build/sample.gif
```

Then set the complete path to run.sh in front of Executable field